# Java Run Thread on Another Machine

Tags: java, multithreading, ssh

In Java, we can easily create a new Thread using new Thread(Runnable r).  However, this uses Threads from our local machine.

Is there a way to connect to another machine (via ssh) and run a function on a new Thread on that machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to connect to another machine (via ssh) and run a function on a new Thread on that machine?

The short answer is no.  There are many [Java implementations of SSH](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) which allow you to login and run *commands* on another system.  This means that you can run another instance of Java (JVM) on another system.  You can run this remote command in a local thread, but you cannot fork a "thread" on a remote system.

The long answer is that there are many other ways of remoting an operation which usually mean running some sort of server on a remote machine that takes requests and returns responses.  There are then many ways to encrypt the remoting protocols.  SSL requests over HTTP to a web-server is one mechanism.  [RMI over SSL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/socketfactory/SSLInfo.html) is another.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java RMI to run the code on another machine.  I've never done it, but apparently you can do this over SSH.

[java RMI via SSH v2 protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734558/java-rmi-via-ssh-v2-protocol)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar to this using Amazon's [Simple Queue Service](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) - machine1 sent Runnables (serialized with [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)) through the queue which were then picked up and executed on machine2.  Simple Queue Service has a free tier for small-scale use, but there are plenty of open-source messaging libraries/programs e.g. [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq) or [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/).